# How to detect real value change in GXT Combobox

Tags: javascript, gwt, combobox, gxt

I'm new to Ext GWT and working with GXT (2.2.5). I want to add an alert when a combo-box changes its value. But the change event fire when re-select the same item. This is part of my code:

```
    @override
    public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
        if (be.getType() == Events.Change) {
            //add alert
        }
    }
```

I wonder how to get the REAL value change event. And if it doesn't exist, how can I get the previous value from the combo-box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem using Field::getOriginalValue(), though not very pretty..

```
@override
public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
    Field<Object> field = (Field<Object>) be.getSource();

    boolean valueChanged = ((ModelData)field.getValue()).get("value").equals(((ModelData)field.getOriginalValue()).get("value"))

    if (be.getType() == Events.Change && valueChanged) {
        //add alert
    }
}
```